# Nginx as Reverse SSL Proxy and browser freeze on redirect

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

The set-up:

Nginx 0.8.54 serves as a reverse SSL proxy to Apache.

Web application being served is used in this way - we upload multiple text files, process them and re-direct user to a page displaying processed results.

The problem:

On uploading files the re-direct starts but then a web browser freezes for a few seconds (eventually coming back to life). After that the re-direct successfully completes.

Since there is no problem of this kind when going directly through Apache the bottleneck must be in Nginx's proxy settings.

I've looked here http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule and here http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size.

Could you, guys, help to pinpoint which of the settings need adjusting to prevent browsers from freezing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a buffer size issue since both the upload and the redirect are both working. I would suspect some misconfiguration in reverse proxy config, maybe in rewriting, so the first step I would take to debug this problem is check HTTP traffic with httpfox or similar tool and see where the time is going